# Check a collection of prices against an associated collection of minimum prices

Tags: c#, javascript, algorithm

I would like to find a more efficient way to solve this problem.  My current implementation has 3 separate loops through the data.

I'm creating an algorithm to check a collection of prices against an associated collection of minimum prices. Any price that is below the minimum must be adjusted up to meet the minimum. The sum of all upward adjustments must then be taken from the other prices in the collection that are above the minimum.

Consider the following data:

> ```
> Line Price Minimum
> ----------------------------------
> 1    16    22
> 2    12    20
> 3    120   90
> 4    25    20
> ```

Lines 1 and 2 require an additional 14 points to meet the minimum values. I would need to take 14 from lines 3 and 4 which are greater than the minimum. Additionally I want to take the amount from 3 and 4 based on their proportions to the sum of their prices (i.e. 145).

> ```
> Line   %                    Amount
> -----------------------------------------------------
> 3      120/145 = .8275%     14 * .8275 = 11.585
> 4      25/145  = .1725%     14 * .1725 =  2.415
>                  ---------               ------------
>           Total   1.00%                  14.000
> ```

Finally I must ensure that when I reduce an above-minimum price I do not cause them to fall below their respective minimums. I have a working version of this adjustment & allocation algorithm but it's **UGLY** and I would really like to find a more elegant way to solve the problem.

I need a more efficient solution that reduces the number of loops through the item collection. Note: that I have used the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tags because this algorithm will need to be implemented in both languages.

Here is the working example of my C# console test program. This is a single file, ready to go code sample.

---

## C# Solution

Following this C# sample is a JavaScript example:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //  Setup testing data
        var linePriceInfos = new LinePriceInfo[]
        {
            new LinePriceInfo(16, 22),
            new LinePriceInfo(12, 20), 
            new LinePriceInfo(120, 90),
            new LinePriceInfo(25, 20)
        };

        PrintValue("Line values before minimum price adjustment", 
            linePriceInfos);

        //  Adjust prices up to meet the minimums, keep track of the 
        //  "amount borrowed" to reach the minimum
        decimal loan = 0;
        foreach (LinePriceInfo info in linePriceInfos)
        {
            if (info.Price < info.Min)
            {
                loan += info.Min - info.Price;
                info.Price = info.Min;
            }
        }

        //  It may take several passes through the items to adjust everything
        while (loan > 0)
        {
            //  The amount a non-minimum priced item gives up will be 
            //  proportionate to it's price
            decimal totalAboveMinPrice = 0;
            decimal totalProfit = 0;
            foreach (var info in linePriceInfos)
            {
                totalProfit += Math.Max(info.Price - info.Min, 0);

                if (info.Price > info.Min)
                    totalAboveMinPrice += info.Price;
            }

            //  This is crude, basically just prevents the while() going into 
            //  an infinite loop. If the total "above minimum" is less than 
            //  the loan amount it's impossible to adjust items without going 
            //  below the minimum somewhere
            if (totalProfit < loan)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    "Impossible to adjust item allocations with minimums");
            }

            //  Repay the "loan" from the items that are priced above the 
            //  minimum
            decimal totalPayments = 0;
            foreach (var info in linePriceInfos)
            {
                //  If the current item is priced at the minimum there is 
                //  nothing for it to give up - skip it
                if (info.Price <= info.Min) continue;

                //  Calculate the loan payment amount for this item
                decimal loanPaymentReq = (info.Price / totalAboveMinPrice) * loan;

                //  Ensure that we do not set the item price below it's minimum
                decimal newPrice = Math.Max(info.Price - loanPaymentReq, info.Min);

                //  The actual amount of the payment to the loan
                decimal loanPayment = info.Price - newPrice;

                info.Price = newPrice;

                //  Temp hack to deal with n.99999999999999999999999999997
                totalPayments += loanPayment;
            }

            //  Reduce the loan by the total of the payments made this pass
            loan -= decimal.Round(totalPayments, 12);
        }

        PrintValue("Line values after minimum price adjustment", linePriceInfos);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void PrintValue(string message, LinePriceInfo[] lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        foreach (var line in lines)
            Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

internal sealed class LinePriceInfo
{
    internal LinePriceInfo(decimal price, decimal min)
    {
        Price = price;
        Min = min;
    }

    internal decimal Price { get; set; }
    internal decimal Min { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Price: {0:0.0000}, Min: {1:0.0000}", Price, Min);
    }
}
```

---

## Javascript Solution

The JavaScript example is my most current version. It's the same approach, but I've just added some helper methods to the `LinePriceInfo` object.

```js
function LinePriceInfo(price, min)
{
    this.price = price;
    this.min = min;
}
LinePriceInfo.prototype.isBelowMinimum = function()
{ 
    return this.price < this.min;
}
LinePriceInfo.prototype.isAboveMinimum = function()
{ 
    return this.price > this.min;
}
LinePriceInfo.prototype.getPriceDelta = function()
{
    return this.min - this.price;
}
LinePriceInfo.prototype.setToMin = function()
{
    this.price = this.min;
}
LinePriceInfo.prototype.toString = function()
{
    return 'Price: ' + this.price + ', Min: ' + this.min;
}

var linePriceInfos =
[
    new LinePriceInfo(16,  22),
    new LinePriceInfo(12,  20),
    new LinePriceInfo(120, 90),
    new LinePriceInfo(25,  20)
];


Allocate(linePriceInfos);


function Allocate(infos)
{
    var loan = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
    {
        var info = infos[i];
        if(info.isBelowMinimum())
        {
            loan += info.getPriceDelta();
            info.setToMin();
        }
    }

    while(loan > 0)
    {
        var totalAboveMinimumPrice = 0;
        var totalProfit = 0;
        var info;
        for(var i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
        {
            info = infos[i];
            totalProfit += Math.max(info.price - info.min, 0);
            if(info.isAboveMinimum())
            {
                totalAboveMinimumPrice += info.price;
            }
        }

        if(totalProfit < loan)
        {
            throw 'can\'t solve!';
        }

        var totalPayments = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
        {
            info = infos[i];
            if(info.price <= info.min)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var loanPaymentReq = (info.price / totalAboveMinimumPrice) * loan;
            var newPrice = Math.max(info.price - loanPaymentReq, info.min);
            var loanPayment = info.price - newPrice;

            info.price = newPrice;
            totalPayments += loanPayment;
        }

        loan -= totalPayments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: Can you provide the end state for your example? Just so that I can verify my algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question,

I am just going to talk about the JavaScript, I know nothing about C#. Though I will point out that your JavaScript code probably has comment envy ;)

**Naming**

In essence you seem to raise prices to a minimum, which increases the sum of prices. Then you need to reduce the other prices proportionally so that the sum total remains the same. Your variable names with `profit` make sense to me, the ones refering to `payment`, `loan`.

- I would suggest to call the sum total of rate increases to match minimum price 
  `missing`
- Similarly, I would call the sum total of surplus rates ( delta between price and minimum price) `surplus`

**Abstraction**

I think you abstracted at the wrong level, it was extremely hard to follow the math because you replaced it with on-liner functions. My general rule of thumb is to avoid one-liners that you only use once. I would have created the abstraction on the collection level, something like

```
var model = new PricingModel(data);
model.allocate();
```

And keep all the logic inside `allocate`

**Proportions**

I had to bring this up, because my counter suggestion proportions differently.

If you have have to split `missing` over these 2 lines:

```
Price       Minimum
1000        990
100         10
```

Then your code would try to reduce `1000` far more because the price is so much higher. I would suggest that you split over the `margin` since the price with the highest margin can take it better. Hope that makes sense..

**Counter Code**

```
function LinePriceInfo(price, min)
{
    this.price = price;
    this.min = min;
}

var linePriceInfos =
[
    new LinePriceInfo(16,  22),
    new LinePriceInfo(12,  20),
    new LinePriceInfo(120, 90),
    new LinePriceInfo(25,  20)
];

Allocate(linePriceInfos);

function Allocate(infos)
{
    var missing = 0,  //Sum total of rate increases to match minimum price
        surplus = 0,  //Sum total of surplus rates ( delta between price and minmum price)
        info, i;

    //Analyze each line 
    for(i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
    {
        info = infos[i];
        //Is the price too low, then fix the price and updating `missing`
        if(info.price <= info.min)
        {
            missing += (this.min - this.price);
            info.price = info.min;
        } 
        //Maintain surplus, adding 0 in case the price was too low is a non-operation
        info.bonus = info.price - info.min;
        surplus += info.bonus;
    }  

    //The missing rates have to be distributed, check whether this is possible
    var newSurplus = surplus - missing;
    if( newSurplus < 0 ){
      throw 'can\'t solve!';      
    }

    //Analyze each line and add back the newly derived surplus 
    for(i = 0; i < infos.length; i++)
    {
        info = infos[i];
        if( info.bonus ){
          info.price = info.min + info.bonus / surplus * newSurplus;
        }
    }         
}
```